# How to truncate the values of a column of a spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to remove the last two values of a string for each string in a single column of a spark dataframe. I would like to do this in the spark dataframe not by moving it to pandas and then back.

An example dataframe would be below,

```
# +----+-------+
# | age|   name|
# +----+-------+
# | 350|Michael|
# | 290|   Andy|
# | 123| Justin|
# +----+-------+
```

where the dtype of the age column is a string.

```
# +----+-------+
# | age|   name|
# +----+-------+
# |   3|Michael|
# |   2|   Andy|
# |   1| Justin|
# +----+-------+
```

This is the expected output. The last two characters of the string have been removed.

Answer (score 4):

Hi Scala/sparkSql way of doing this is very Simple.

```
val result = originalDF.withColumn("age", substring(col("age"),0,1))
result.show
```

you can probably get your syntax for pyspark

Comment: Taking the first character is not the same as removing the last 2. What if the string had 4 characters?

Comment: case can be made if the string has 2 characters as well what would have been the outcome? a null ?. which could be avoided by taking the first character.  User can clarify more on the use case.  anyways Like i said both the approaches are correct in their respective manner.  one more prone to giving the first character irrespective of the string length. the other answer the user question as it was posted.

Answer (score -1):

`substring`, `length`, `col`, `expr` from functions  can be used for this purpose.

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length, col, expr
```

df = your df here

> substring index 1, -2 were used since its 3 digits and .... its age field logically a person
>   wont live more than 100 years :-) OP can change substring function suiting to his requirement.

```
df.withColumn("age",expr("substring(age, 1, length(age)-2)"))
df.show
```

Result :

```
+----+-------+
 | age|   name|
 +----+-------+
 |   3|Michael|
 |   2|   Andy|
 |   1| Justin|
 +----+-------+
```

Scala answer :

```
val originalDF =  Seq(
      (350, "Michael"),
      (290, "Andy"),
      (123, "Justin")
    ).toDF("age", "name")
println(" originalDF " )

    originalDF.show
    println("modified")
    originalDF.selectExpr("substring(age,0,1) as age", "name "  ).show
```

Result :

```
 originalDF 
+---+-------+
|age|   name|
+---+-------+
|350|Michael|
|290|   Andy|
|123| Justin|
+---+-------+

modified
+---+-------+
|age|   name|
+---+-------+
|  3|Michael|
|  2|   Andy|
|  1| Justin|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: Hi Ram, I think doing age -2 would not be a good idea because it can introduce error  if the data has  length of anything other that 3. the  reason why I i kept it to  hardcoded  value of 0 ,1.  would that not make it more robust.

Comment: :-) thats age normally a person wont live 1000 years it will be max 100 years thats the reason i went a head boldly. would you like to revisit the vote :-)

Comment: that was not my intent. rather I have seen people ask question in pseudo terms. I don't think age of 350 also makes sense let alone 1250.  god Bless if we all live that long.

Comment: yeah understood. thats was an example  of approach of how to achive it. if data varies users can change the substring. its very simple :-)

Comment: @RamGhadiyaramRam i'm not sure what this answer adds that's not already addressed in the duplicate.

Comment: i have seen your duplicate comments lately and moreover I added scala answer as well for scala users. there was an edit with scala tag as well please see the edit request to the question.